# "Jump" over deleted rows

Tags: c#, datatable

My datatable contains a large number of empty rows that are deleted. I'm using the following code to split the table into several new tables based on the value of `Printers`, however I need to add contingency for those deleted rows. How can I add this contingency within the following statement?

```
List<DataTable> dtCollection = dt.AsEnumerable()
                   .GroupBy(row => row.Field<string>("Printers"))
                   .Select(g => g.CopyToDataTable())
                   .ToList();`
```

My theory is that I should be able to create some sort of bool within `GroupBy`, but I'm not sure how to approach this.

Comment: What is '*contingency  for deleted rows*'?

Comment: Condional inclusion of a row is specified by `Where`, not `GroupBy`.

Comment: Perhaps add a `.Where()` that checks if the result is not null or empty

Comment: @SergeyBerezovskiy Some form of if statement or where condition to check if the row is deleted, and return it if it is not.

Comment: Why are you using a DataTable for this in the first place? Why not use strongly typed models?

Comment: @EricLippert so I could conceivably use `.Where((row => row.Field<string>("Printers")).Exists)`?

Comment: @mason I'm not writing an MVC application, just a basic tool to upload data to a database based on several conditions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to filter out those rows which were deleted, then you can use simple `Where` statement which checks state of a row:

```
List<DataTable> dtCollection = dt.AsEnumerable()
                   .Where(row => row.RowState != DataRowState.Deleted)
                   .GroupBy(row => row.Field<string>("Printers"))
                   .Select(g => g.CopyToDataTable())
                   .ToList();
```